# How to avoid too many new lines in swift

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I am using a text View for content input for users, but I cannot limit the amount of times user hits enter to create new lines, how can I limit the textView to 2 new lines max?

Example:

current

```
"Start





end"
```

Desired:

```
"limit


2 


empty lines"
```

Comment: that helped thanks boss

Answer (score 3):

You can make your view controller the delegate of your text view and use replacingOccurrences to replace 4 or more new lines with 3 new lines, you would need to avoid new lines also at the beginning of your string:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textView.delegate = self
    }
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // avoid new lines also at the beginning
        textView.text = textView.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "^\n", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        // avoids 4 or more new lines after some text
        textView.text = textView.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n{4,}", with: "\n\n\n", options: .regularExpression)
    }
}
```